# Seeking Australian Topo Map GeoTIFFs

Tags: data, geotiff-tiff, topography, australia

Does anyone know if Australian topo map GeoTIFFs are made available anywhere (preferably for free)?

[LINZ](http://www.linz.govt.nz/) makes them available in New Zealand - http://www.linz.govt.nz/topography/topo-maps/index.aspx, and I was hoping a similar service was available for Australia.

Answer (score 3):

[MapConnect has 1:250k data](http://www.ga.gov.au/mapconnect/) for download in many formats, including as ECW rasters which can be converted to GeoTiff with GDAL if needed. They also have a partial coverage of [1:50k topographic maps](http://www.ga.gov.au/bin/mapserv36?querymode=&mode=browse&zoomdir=0&map_gaz_x=0&map_gaz_y=0&map_gaz_name=%5Bmap_gaz_name%5D&cat_type=&layers=index50kTLM&INPUT_TYPE=&INPUT_COORD=&qlayer=prod&map=/public/http/www/docs/oracle/agsocat/geocat.map&zoomsize=4&mapsize=440%20270&imgxy=219.5%20134.5&imgext=-3155555.555556%20-5000000.000000%202955555.555556%20-1250000.000000), but they cost money.

If you're interested in creating your own topographic maps, check out [TopOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TopOSM), which aims to produce high-quality topographic maps from open data, and includes the source code to do so if you're willing to get your hands dirty. You might also find some hints in [this quesion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/open-terrain-map-tiles).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried SRTM3 data for Australia? Roughly 90m resolution. Would need to convert though. 
http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Australia/

Comment: From what I've seen from online screenshots it looks like hgt files will be a little raw for my requirements. I'm looking more for the type of imagery used by http://www.topomap.co.nz - but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: SRTM3 data is probably comparable or better then the example. You should give it a try. You can easily convert the files in any GIS software. I believe you can actually view the data in ArcGIS without any conversion. You will need to generate a shaded relief from the dem which is also a fairly simple task. It is likely that any data at this scale will be generated from the SRTM3 files.

Comment: Remember that with the HGT file you have to get the geocoding from the file *name*, i.e. in SRTM filename the coordinates are the *center* of the respective lower left pixel.

Answer (score -1):

Geoscience Australia have the 250K raster topo on DVD for A$99. Check out this URL:
https://www.ga.gov.au/products/servlet/controller?event=GEOCAT_DETAILS&catno=65047

Comment: Not too expensive in the scheme of things - I wonder if I could get some sample rasters first to check out quality first. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score -1):

Geoscience Australia (GA) now offers a bunch of coverages via Web Coverage Service, which you can probably plug straight into your GIS software or query directly yourself.

The topo data is here: http://www.ga.gov.au/gis/services/marine_coastal/Australian_Bathymetry_Topography/MapServer/WCSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS

and the list of all the webservices available is here: http://www.ga.gov.au/data-pubs/web-services/ga-web-services