# Looking for detailed relief tiles

Tags: tiles, topography

A few days ago I stumbled over a map which had beautifully rendered, detailed topographic tiles of the whole world. It was similar to google-physical with a strong contrast (shadow/light) and contour-lines. I do believe it was not from a commercial provider like ArcGIS but an open platform (Not sure though). I stumbled over it in relation to a search for openlayers.
Unfortunately I missed to bookmark the site, I can't find the link in my history anymore. Does anyone know what I'm mumbling about or could post examples of topographic tiles which fit the description?

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/are-there-open-access-terrain-tiles-with-a-permissive-license-like-osm) is very similar to what I'm looking for (And much better worded), but it's 2 years old and partly outdated

Comment: OpenCycle (OSM Based) Landscape Terrain http://www.opencyclemap.org/?zoom=11&lat=28.67546&lon=83.80079&layers=00B00- look up your history in your browser to find the url you were looking at.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been a few days and i've visited hundreds of links in the meanwhile, the link is lost in the noise (Or maybe i've just dreamed it :-))

Comment: @Mapperz looks like you brought me on the right track - i believe what i saw was the landscape-tiles from http://www.thunderforest.com/landscape/ - i saw it used somewhere else but i'm pretty sure it's the same :-) You can add that as an answer if you want those internet-points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenCycle (OSM Based) Landscape Terrain (ThunderForest)**

created and all credit goes to Andy Allan http://www.gravitystorm.co.uk/projects/

> "The Thunderforest Platform is the 4th major revision of the systems
> that powers OpenCycleMap."

[image]

See the tiles here around Sagarmāthā & Chomolungma (Mount Everest)

http://www.opencyclemap.org/?zoom=11&lat=28.67546&lon=83.80079&layers=00B00-

Tiles are

```
https://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/12/2997/1705.png
https://b.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/12/2997/1705.png
https://c.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/12/2997/1705.png
```

*but seek pricing and authorized access [Free for a 'Hobby Project']

http://www.thunderforest.com/pricing/