# Searching open source Terrain and Satellite maps for Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, open-source-gis, basemap

For our project, we are exploring Terrain and Satellite maps using Leaflet.js

While exploring the Internet got this [OpenTopoMap](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=OpenTopoMap). However, not sure whether this is a Terrain Map.

For Satellite got this [Esri.WorldImagery](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Esri.WorldImagery). However, as the map source is https://server.arcgisonline.com don't know whether these are open source maps or paid maps.

Also, is there any open source basemap like OSM for Terrain and Satellite maps?

Comment: Related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/are-there-open-access-terrain-tiles-with-a-permissive-license-like-osm

Comment: Do you need the entire world? Or just a particular area? The reason I ask is that some basemaps are only available for the United States.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Esri) Esri World Imagery can be used free of cost when all of the following conditions are met:

1. You have signed up for a free ArcGIS Developer account
2. You are not generating revenue from your app (in the form of advertisements or subscriptions)
3. Your users request < 1 million tiles/month
4. You properly attribute both Esri and all of our data providers